# How to make my toolbar overlap the content

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I have tried things like `"app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in my `content layout`, but in my case the `recyclerview` of my content layout shines through the toolbar. How can I make the toolbar cover other content completely?

Comment: What have you tried.Post your code.What you want is also not clear

Comment: i want a simple thing. that my toolbar (logobar) covers my content (recyclerview row).

Comment: Do you want that your one row of recyclerview is covered by toolbar

Comment: yes, exactly. and i made the bad solution wit negative margin. but it works fine for me if i can cover it

Comment: i would appreciate every help :)

Answer (score 0):

this is my toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:id="@+id/logobar">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/tv_header_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/logo"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this is my recycler layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2">
<!--android:background="@color/backgroundColor"-->



<include
    layout="@layout/logobar_layout"
    ></include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
   android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"



>
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
  ></include>


</RelativeLayout>
```